# Generic type List shows same value each time in PrimeFaces datatable in spring framework. I add component to the List by looping

Tags: java, spring, primefaces

When I want to show data in datatable through getListPortfolio() method it shows lastly added value for many times.

This is my ManageBean where method is created. Codes are Following.

```
@Controller
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
@Transactional

public class MbPortfolio {

    @Autowired
    Portfolio portfolio;

    @Autowired
    TransactionService transactionService;

    public Portfolio getPortfolio() {
        return portfolio;
    }

    public void setPortfolio(Portfolio portfolio) {
        this.portfolio = portfolio;
    }

    public TransactionService getTransactionService() {
        return transactionService;
    }

    public void setTransactionService(TransactionService transactionService) {
        this.transactionService = transactionService;
    }

    public List<Portfolio> getListPortfolio() {
        List <Transaction> lst = transactionService.clientPortfolio();
        System.out.println(lst.size()+ "lkdlkdkgfkldglkfkljfljklkgfl");
        List <Portfolio> lst2=new ArrayList<Portfolio>();

        for (int i = 0; i < lst.size(); i++) {
            portfolio.setShareCode(lst.get(i).getClient().getClientName());
            lst2.add(portfolio);
        }
        return lst2;

    }
}
```

And here is my Portfolio class.

```
public class Portfolio  extends Transaction implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String shareCode;
    private Double shareAmount;
    private Double shareCostPrice;
    private Double shareTotalCostPrice;
    private Double shareMarketPrice;
    private Double shareTotalMarketPrice;

    public Portfolio() {
    }

    public Portfolio(String shareCode, Double shareAmount, Double shareCostPrice, Double shareTotalCostPrice, Double shareMarketPrice, Double shareTotalMarketPrice) {
        this.shareCode = shareCode;
        this.shareAmount = shareAmount;
        this.shareCostPrice = shareCostPrice;
        this.shareTotalCostPrice = shareTotalCostPrice;
        this.shareMarketPrice = shareMarketPrice;
        this.shareTotalMarketPrice = shareTotalMarketPrice;
    }

    public String getShareCode() {
        return shareCode;
    }

    public void setShareCode(String shareCode) {
        this.shareCode = shareCode;
    }

    public Double getShareAmount() {
        return shareAmount;
    }

    public void setShareAmount(Double shareAmount) {
        this.shareAmount = shareAmount;
    }

    public Double getShareCostPrice() {
        return shareCostPrice;
    }

    public void setShareCostPrice(Double shareCostPrice) {
        this.shareCostPrice = shareCostPrice;
    }

    public Double getShareTotalCostPrice() {
        return shareTotalCostPrice;
    }

    public void setShareTotalCostPrice(Double shareTotalCostPrice) {
        this.shareTotalCostPrice = shareTotalCostPrice;
    }

    public Double getShareMarketPrice() {
        return shareMarketPrice;
    }

    public void setShareMarketPrice(Double shareMarketPrice) {
        this.shareMarketPrice = shareMarketPrice;
    }

    public Double getShareTotalMarketPrice() {
        return shareTotalMarketPrice;
    }

    public void setShareTotalMarketPrice(Double shareTotalMarketPrice) {
        this.shareTotalMarketPrice = shareTotalMarketPrice;
    }

}
```

It shows lastly added name for many times. please help me.

Comment: Transaction is also a bean where Client is a object which has clientName property. It has getter and setters.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < lst.size(); i++) {
    portfolio.setShareCode(lst.get(i).getClient().getClientName());
    lst2.add(portfolio);
}
```

- here, you always add the same object to the list. You may think you're adding a copy of the object, but in reality you're adding a reference. So what happens here is each iteration, you change the object, then add another reference to it in the list.

- First iteration,  you set `portfolio`'s `shareCode` to first client name, then add it to the list

  - Now you have a list with one entry having the first client's name
- Second iteration, you set the `portfolio`'s `shareCode` to second client name

  - This is the same object you used in first iteration, and stored in the list, so accessing the first value of the list you'll see the second client name already
  - Then you add `portfolio` to the list again, so now you have two entries in the list that both list the second client name
- ...

Comment: portfolio is autowired. So how can i add another reference in the list? @Jiri Tousek

Comment: How does it relate to `getListPortfolio()`? Why is it used within that method?

Comment: The `getListPortfolio() ` return list of Transaction class type List. I want to get a `Portfolio` type List which values will be set from `Transaction` type list.

Comment: But why do you use the autowired `Portfolio` instance for that?

Comment: Its a spring framework and I try hard to reduce dependency.

Comment: I'm afraid you in fact instead of reducing dependencies added one to your code that doesn't really exist - your `getListPortfolio()` now depends on the injected instance of `Portfolio` - what does that injected instance really represent? I suggest you take a step back and consider what your code is really supposed to do.  Only inject dependencies if they're real, meaningful objects that have some relation to the problem you're solving.